# Git how to transfer changes between branches?

Tags: git, github

If I have added something in master branch then I decided that it need to be in a purposely created branch, called `some-branch`.

Those new files changed in master are now green. I do not want to commit them in master but in the new branch that I have forgot to create befor I have made the changes.

So how to commit changes for a different branch?

Comment: Green where? If that’s in `git status`, that means they’re staged for commit, not actually committed. You can check out the new branch and commit.

Comment: Green in the edtior - I have meant that they were modified, not yet added.

Comment: @Raz what editor, what are you talking about? Please try to use proper git terminology. What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: If you have merely made changes in the working directory, then it is incorrect to say that you have 'added something in master branch'.  You haven't added anything to the master branch. The fact that you had the master branch checked out when you modified files in the working directory is (almost) completely irrelevant.

Comment: Opened index.html -> wrote: <p>hello</p>. Oh oops I forgot to add this in a specific branch that I forgot to create.

I just need to bring the <p> from master to the new branch. I have not done any git comment yet, even not git add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the branch doesn't have conflicting changes, you can `git checkout` your new branch with those changes (without committing) and they will remain.

Comment: But I do not want them to remain in master, but only in the new branch

Comment: I mean they will remain unstaged.  Unstaged changes are not associated with any branch.

Comment: Thats true and worked. But the new folder that I created in master is now remain empy on master, while its full of content in the new branch which I have git add it there, I had to delete this manually from master.

Comment: Creating a folder doesn’t automatically make it “on master”. If you make a folder and switch branch, that folder will stay there.

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
1. git reset (if changes are staged/added for commit)  
2. git checkout -b newbranch  
or  
git checkout newbranch (if branch is already there)
```

Another way:

```
1. git reset  (if changes are staged/added for commit)  
2. git stash    
3. git checkout -b newbranch or git checkout newbranch if branch is already there.  
4. git stash pop
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

If you haven't made a new branch, try this:

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

If you want to move these commits to a branch that already exists, try this:

```
git checkout existingbranch
```

Here are some helpful resources that worth checking out:

https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/04/01/git-oops-i-changed-those-files-in-the-wrong-branch/

Also, https://git-scm.com/ has always been a great git resource for me.

Hope this helps. Good luck!